# Memory Limits, 500 Error, Huge Uploading Issues

Tags: php, file-upload, ini

read around on some answers and never found something that directly related to my issue.

I have a 48Megabyte .csv file I am trying to upload and run so the clients can do a massive product update/insert. We can occasionally get the upload to work, but right now I'm getting a 500 Error returned on my Ajax request. Here are some of the details:

**Our server support set the maximum upload file size to 100 Megabytes.**

I am using the following ini_sets at the top of the script:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Here's where I think the problem is. Due to the amount of testing I have to do to make this script work; I probably do about 10 uploads a day. This is really stressing the server, as well as the fact that their site is receiving about 500 visits a day at the moment as well.

Monthly Bandwidth Transfer: 12775.43 / 3000 MB

Any ideas I can return to my boss with regarding this issue? It kinda needed to be done today, and I'm still working on cleaning issues but if it's a bandwidth thing then we can't do the test again until tomorrow when the server resets it's monthly bandwidth.

Thanks for any ideas.

**Notes: This has worked in the past. If I do smaller sized files, it works just as well, but the client explicitly requires us to use this 48 Megabyte .csv file.**

**Notes again: It seems like the upload tool is working to an extent because it posts and uploads to the folder I want it to post to. The problem I think is that after spending 10 minutes uploading and preparing the file, it doesn't have long to parse all the data and times out.**

**Another set of notes: Following is the 500 Internal Server issue:**

**The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@*_*__*_*.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

Comment: AFAIK `ini_set()` won't work for `upload_max_filesize` as it gets called AFTER the attempted file upload.  You have to change it in your php.ini settings.

Comment: The ini_setting was set by the server administrator in the php.ini settings and I accidentally included it on here an old script. PHPINFO() says I have 100M of upload_max_filesize.

Comment: Error log reporting nothing regarding this. Last error was four hours ago, regarding a different issue with the site.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is of any help.

https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/issues/61

> I've tested uploading large files (a 20MB+ file with a 64MB php memory setting), and got consistent memory maxed out errors from PHP, because it was loading the uploaded XHR content into $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA. 
>   Despite setting always_populate_raw_post_data to false it kept doing this, and as the docs are a little sparse on the issue, I had trouble solving it. Turns out, if you fake the content type to "multipart/form-data", PHP does not populate $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA (I tried other content types, this is the only one that seems to work), and you can upload large files without hitting a low memory limit. Binary integrity is mantained, at least with Chrome and Firefox, which is what I tried.*

I found it here:

[Reduce memory consumption in PHP while handling uploads by php input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430021/reduce-memory-consumption-in-php-while-handling-uploads-by-php-input)

Comment: I'm trying this one out. I took over the project from a development company in India. Turns out, his form class didn't have an enctype set up for the upload form, so I got that put in. The upload SHOULD take approximately 10 minutes max, and if it takes longer than that I usually consider it non-functional.

Comment: Upload/Parsing currently on 21 minutes or so. Usually 500's by this time, but still taking much longer than usual. Thanks for your input, but I feel like something is wrong with the time out for parsing the file, because the upload itself works just fine.

Comment: 500 Internal Error. See post edit for the copied error received.